# $scope is not defined in a directive controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I have a very basic demo app. The HTML:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="Shapes">
    <shapes></shapes>
</div>
```

and my js file:

```
app.directive('shape',
    function () {
        var directive = {};
        directive.restrict = 'E';
        directive.template = '<span>Shape Name: {{shape.Name}}, Shape Area: {{shape.Area}}</span>';
        directive.scope = {
            shape: "=name"
        };

        return directive;
    });

app.directive('shapes',
    function () {
        var controller = [
           '$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
                $scope.height = 0, $scope.width = 0;

               $http.get('/api/Values').then(function (respnse) {
                    $scope.shapes = respnse.data;
               });

               $scope.addShape = function () {
                   $http.post('api/Values', { Width: 1, Height: 1 }).then(function (res) { });
               };
           }
        ];

        var directive = {};
        directive.restrict = 'E';
        directive.template = '<div ng-repeat="shape in shapes"><shape name="shape"></shape></div>' +
            '<div>Height:<input type="text" ng-model="height"></input>, Width:<input type="text" ng-model="width"></input>' +
            '<button ng-click="addShape()">Add Shape</button></div>';
        directive.controller = controller;

        return directive;
    });
```

My problem - in the $scope.addShape function, $scope is not defined. Why? $http is defined and working well.

Comment: I think what you are asking is, while debugging addShape function, you see that $http is defined but $scope is not defined, because you have not used $scope inside the function it won't show/get its information, try adding $scope inside the function if you want to access any info from it

Comment: Create a demo that reproduces problem. Not totally clear what you mean by it not being defined either. Is it a console error?

Comment: Your'e right! its all just in the debugger - when I send the parameters height and width to the server its OK! Why is it happening and is there a way to be able to debug it? I have successfully debugged $scope multiple times, but here I can't.